# Não consigo mudar a fonte e o tamanho do texto

Tags: html5, css3

[image: Imagem que peguei na internet]

Olá pessoal!
Estou tentando criar um overlay customizado no obs studio para ficar do mesmo jeito que está na foto.
A parte do balão embaixo eu estou conseguindo fazer, mas estou tendo problema ao tentar mudar o tipo de fonte e o tamanho dela..

Vou postar aqui o código:
HTML

```html
<!-- alert image -->
<div id="alert-image-wrap">
  <div id="alert-image">{img}</div>
</div>

<!-- main alert box window -->
<div id="alert-text-wrap">

  <!-- alert text -->
  <div id="alert-text">

    <!-- alert message -->
    <!-- messageTemplate will be replaced with your message template -->
    <!-- for example : {name} is now following! or {name} donated {amount} -->

    <div id="alert-message">{messageTemplate}</div>
    <div id="alert-user-message" class="balao">{userMessage}</div>

  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@1,200&display=swap');
.widget-AlertBox {
    position: relative;
}
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#wrap {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#alert-box {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
#alert-box.hidden,
.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
#alert-text {
    padding: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #000, 0px 0px 2px #000, 0px 0px 3px #000, 0px 0px 4px #000, 0px 0px 5px #000;
}
#alert-message,
#alert-user-message {
    text-align: center;
}
#alert-user-message img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 1em;
}
#alert-image {
    position: relative;
}
#alert-image video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#alert-message > span > span {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
}
#alert-image {
    z-index: 6;
    position: relative;
}
#alert-text {
    z-index: 6;
    position: relative;
}
#alert-text-wrap {
    z-index: 6;
    position: relative;
}
.balao {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-size: 0.85em;
    line-height: 1.6em;  
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    color: 242424;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.balao:after{ /*Triangulo*/
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
    top: -10px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

Eu não consigo mudar a fonte e o tamanho da classe "BALAO", ele simplemente não ativa..
Se alguem puder me dar uma ajuda nisso..

Answer (score -2):

Olá, amigo! Ao que me parece você está tentando modificar o texto com esse seletor:

```
#alert-message > span > span {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Com isso, na verdade, está alterando o texto de um span filho de outro span que é filho da div. Tente alterar apenas o texto da div.

Abraço e boa sorte!

Comment: Bom, eu ainda continuo com o mesmo problema. A alteração não está salvando ou eu estou editando no lugar errado.. Vou ir tentando aqui e depois retorno com a resposta.

Answer (score -2):

Vamos lá, reproduzi o seu cenário no seguinte link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-fqw7ue?file=style.css

Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas a `div` onde temos a "{userMessage}" tem a classe `balao` ao qual você se referiu... Observe que alterei os elementos:
font-family e font-size dela... Era essa sua questão?

Ideia: se não quiser seguir pelo caminho de alterar a classe `balao` diretamente, você pode colocar o "{userMessage}" em um elemento separado e manipulá-lo a partir disto...

Comment: O que você mandou da certo se eu for fazer no navegador, porém como estou fazendo no streamlabs ele não está fazendo a devida alteração no código, a caixa do {userMessage} continua da mesma maneira sem alterar as suas propriedades. Mesmo Criando um elemento separado ele ainda continua com o mesmo erro de não fazer as alterações.